# Is there any way to detect if a website is using any cookie consent tool?

Tags: javascript, cookies, puppeteer

Actually, I need to determine if a site is using a cookie consent tool for managing its cookies or not. I would like to check this via running a script on any site via puppeteer js and so, is there any way with which I could check if a site is indeed using any cookie consent tool? Also, is there any way to check it via cookies only?

I tried to find if there's any cookie that might indicate that but so, far I couldn't.

Comment: Doubt it.......

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.